Conditional interpretation of Deming regression
I have a set of x-y data $(x_i,y_i)$ that have "dispersion" in both x and y. So, I've been fitting a straight line to them using Deming regression. As an aside, I'm using Deming and not orthogonal regression because x and y have different units. Anyway, I get my linear fit and I'm happy with it, except that I'd now like to interpret it conditionally: given an x what is the most likely y and dispersion of y? This would correspond $p(y|x)$.
Can I interpret the Deming model in this simple way?
It is confusing because Deming assumes errors in both x and y ... I'm thinking I might need to do some-sort of integration to marginalize things. Possibly assuming that my x value is the most likely value of (say) a normal distribution, then inegrate the product of a normal and the linear model. Not sure about that, though.
Thank you.

For this conditional interpretation, you necessarily are conditioning on the observed value of $x,$ not on its "true" value (without error).  Thus, you should be using ordinary regression.  It already does everything you ask for.

I see. So Deming just gives me the pdf of (X,Y) when they are always as a pair, otherwise I use ordinary least squares (say) to obtain the conditional p(y|x). I suppose I invert things and use ordinary least squares to obtain p(x|y). The two models will not be the same line.
